# Warning when using fflib_QueryFactory

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql, framework, fflib

When performing a sub query, I get the following message:

```
WARN|fflib_QueryFactory.subselectQuery(Schema.SObjectType) is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use fflib_QueryFactory.subselectQuery(String) or fflib_QueryFactory.subselectQuery(ChildRelationship) instead.
```

The code runs successfully, but I received this warning message above. Is there any other way to do a subselect without receiving this message?

```
fflib_QueryFactory faqsQueryFactory = newQueryFactory();        
    fflib_QueryFactory pFactory = new FAQsSelector().
        addQueryFactorySubselect(faqsQueryFactory);       

    return (List<FAQ__c>) Database.query(
        faqsQueryFactory.setCondition('cat__c =: cat AND subC__c =: subc').toSOQL()
    );
```

Comment: The warning itself seems to recommend alternatives. Have you tried them?

Answer (score 0):

If using fflib from at least one year ago, the way to include subselects is given [here in this example](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-common-samplecode/blob/master/fflib-sample-code/src/classes/OpportunitiesSelector.cls?ts=4) selecting Opportunities w/ OpportunityLineItems (and lookup parent PricebookEntryProduct2/Pricebook2

```
public List<Opportunity> selectByIdWithProducts(Set<ID> idSet)
    {
        fflib_QueryFactory opportunitiesQueryFactory = newQueryFactory();

        fflib_QueryFactory lineItemsQueryFactory = 
            new OpportunityLineItemsSelector().
                addQueryFactorySubselect(opportunitiesQueryFactory);

        new PricebookEntriesSelector().
            configureQueryFactoryFields(lineItemsQueryFactory, 'PricebookEntry');
        new ProductsSelector().
            configureQueryFactoryFields(lineItemsQueryFactory, 'PricebookEntry.Product2');
        new PricebooksSelector().
            configureQueryFactoryFields(lineItemsQueryFactory, 'PricebookEntry.Pricebook2');

        return (List<Opportunity>) Database.query(
            opportunitiesQueryFactory.setCondition('id in :idSet').toSOQL());
    }
```